# Compile into one file: require.js needed? gulp needed?

Tags: node.js, typescript, gulp, visual-studio-code, requirejs

I have a big solution written in TypeScript, arranged in a project folder with many subfolders with separate files for each class and interface, which is the correct way I suppose.

For each .ts file I get a .js file compiled, and I can run the code from a web page: I embed the require.js script on the web page, and point it to the entry point of my application - that all works very well.

However, I would prefer not to deploy 100+ tiny .js bits to the webserver. I found the compiler option -outFile, which I understand does exactly that.

I do not yet understand if I do neet require.js at all in this scenario anymore. If all is in one .js file, I need to point my webpage there and make it start the main entry point (I think?).

I do not use any external library in my project, everything I need is in typescript in this project folder and is compiled when running build. No "external modules", if that is the correct term.

I think I understand I do not need the "gulp" project for anything up to here, too?

---

Apart from this web related question, I do want to make part of the code useable from the command line, using node.js.

I got that working as well, however I have no idea how it does it's loading. I have a line

```
/// <reference types="node" />
```

followed by many

```
import * as ...
```

for everything I need. Later on, there is

```
const fs: any = require("fs");
const xml2js: any = require("xml2js");
```

so these are external references. Can this be compiled into one .js file (preferably including the externals?) that can be copied somewhere and run using the "node myfile.js" command?

---

Thinking about it, I guess I made a mistake by with the way I arrange my projects in the first place. Currently, the project folder contains this

.vscode
cmd
library1
library2
library3
web
tsconfig.json

I open this folder in VS Code, compile in it, run from there and so on.

What would be a good folder structure for this, with the goal of compiling ONE .js for the web and ONE .js for the command line?

Answer (score 0):

to get everything compiled to one file, you need webpack.

```
npm install --save-dev webpack
```

then create a webpack.config.js in project root.
configuration is described here:
[Webpack configuration](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/)

calling webpack in the project root compiles everything that is linked directly or indirectly from the entry point file to one .js

a short introduction on how to set up webpack for typescript is [on webpack homepage](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/)